# SQLServer FullText search not returning expected results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

```
select homephone,lastName from DEBTOR where contains((lastName,homephone),'"Smith" AND "99 999 9999"')
```

The first query returns no results with AND clause but works as expected with the OR clause, returning some records with Smith as the last name and some with '99 999 9999' as the phone.

I am trying to emulate the below query in FullText. 
What am I missing?

```
select homephone,lastname from DEBTOR where lastName = 'Smith' and homePhone = '99 999 9999'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column list in the CONTAINS clause is not positional. As you've written the query, you're saying that you want to search *both* the lastName *and* the homephone columns, *and* that one of the columns must contain *both* "Smith" *and* "99 999 9999".

Instead, split it out into two independent CONTAINS operations:

```
SELECT homephone,lastName 
    FROM DEBTOR 
    WHERE CONTAINS(lastName,'"Smith"')
      AND CONTAINS(homephone,'"99 999 9999"')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. So how do i accomplish the result in the second query using fullText so i dont have to use expensive like clauses?